# Resizing the webview content

Tags: android

I am loading image url on to webview it fetching the image as well but i need to display it in resizeable it means te height to be reduced,help me to get reduced height of the image.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest, I think is:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the zoom to show the image zoomed out:

```
this.getWebView ().getSettings ().setSupportZoom ( true );
View zoom = this.getWebView ().getZoomControls ();
FrameLayout contentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow ().getDecorView ().findViewById ( android.R.id.content );
contentView.addView ( zoom, ZOOM_PARAMS );
zoom.setVisibility ( View.GONE );
// set the initial scale that it should display at. the value is the scale percent
this.getWebView ().setInitialScale ( 75 );
```

Comment: If you wonder why people wont answer your questions, it is because you don't ever mark them as answered. I was reluctant to do so, but figured I would help you out...